# Cannot change the umask mode

Tags: arch-linux, permissions, umask

I'm trying to change *umask* mode using *login.defs* config file but for some reason it doesn't affect the system.

This is what I do: `sudo nano /etc/login.defs`

```
# The ERASECHAR and KILLCHAR are used only on System V machines.
# The ULIMIT is used only if the system supports it.
# (now it works with setrlimit too; ulimit is in 512-byte units)
#
# Prefix these values with "0" to get octal, "0x" to get hexadecimal.
#
ERASECHAR       0177
KILLCHAR        025
UMASK           027
```

Trying to change `UMASK 027` to `UMASK 007` and it changes.

Next:

```
# Enable setting of the umask group bits to be the same as owner bits
# (examples: 022 -> 002, 077 -> 007) for non-root users, if the uid is
# the same as gid, and username is the same as the primary group name.
#
# This also enables userdel to remove user groups if no members exist.
#
USERGROUPS_ENAB yes
```

Changing `USERGROUPS_ENAB yes` to `USERGROUPS_ENAB no` after that I save the file and do log out and log in and trying to create a *file* for example:

```
touch file ~/
```

and the output for *file*

```
stat -c %a ~/file
```

gives *644* and not expected *640*. I remember I did this workaround some time ago and it worked perfectly fine.

Is there some other workaround or explanation?

This is my *kernel* information:

```
Linux 4.13.8-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 18 12:11:48 CEST 2017 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Maybe the `login.defs` value is overwritten by a shell init file? (/etc/profile* /etc/bash.bashrc ~/.bashrc)

Comment: Well in profile I find these lines: Set our umask / umask 022 ............ should I change them as well?

Comment: I don't find anything unusual in bash.rc files none of them

Comment: tried to change it in /etc/profile but same story.... As far as I remeber I didn't do any changes to either bash.rc or profile before

Comment: /etc/login.defs it's where I'm trying to change it as stated in my OP

Comment: there's no /etc/default/login as I can find in my system

Comment: Have you configured `pam_umask`? Are you using Gnome?

Comment: Nope I'm not using Gnome either I'm using Cinnamon... And yes I even tried to create *pam* module but it still won't change.. if I run for e.g. `umask 077` in a current session it does work. But to make it permanent it just won't do it and I can't get it what's causing it...

Comment: If `umask` works in the shell then it must work in the init files, too. It it seems to not work then I would guess it gets overwritten. You could attach `strace -f` to the process which calls the shell and look for `umask` calls in the `strace` output. Together with the last `open()` call for an init file that may show you where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments who ever tried to help me. So I happened to make `umask 027` mode permanent by changing `~/bashrc` file. For a fact I didn't have any `umask` sets in that file, so I added these lines at the end of the text:

```
#umask mode
umask 027
```

And after system *log out* and *log in* it seems to overwrite this rule for entire system, now the newly created files have permission `640`